# Error in Cannot specify link libraries for target "Opencvtest" which is not built by this project

Tags: opencv, cmake

So, my purpose is trying to set up open cv in VS studio for Opencvtest project/folder through CMakeLists.txt, however in line 11 target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} has an error and I even try to put my folder/project name in targer_link_libraries() still did not know how to fix. I hope you guys can help me with this

Here is the code in CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(Opencvtest VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(Opencvtest main.cpp)
#add_executable(main ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Opencvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Here is the output:

```
    [main] Configuring folder: Opencvtest 
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable):
[cmake]   Cannot find source file:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     main.cpp
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Tried extensions .c .C .c++ .cc .cpp .cxx .cu .mpp .m .M .mm .ixx .cppm .h
[cmake]   .hh .h++ .hm .hpp .hxx .in .txx .f .F .for .f77 .f90 .f95 .f03 .hip .ispc
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_executable):
[cmake]   No SOURCES given to target: Opencvtest
```

Please help me with this problem and thank you so much

Comment: The first argument of the `target_link_libraries` is a name of the **target**, which you want to link. Since you create (via `add_executable`) the target `main`, you should specify it as a first argument: `target_link_libraries(main ${OpenCV_LIBS})`.

Comment: I also tried that but, it result that same, which it gives out 
```
Cannot specify link libraries for target "main" which is not built by this
[cmake]   project.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: Well, the result cannot be the same. When re-run cmake, note on the messages you got: "Changes were detected in CMakeLists.txt but we could not reconfigure the project because another operation is already in progress.".

Comment: So what should I do next?

Comment: "So what should I do next?" - [edit] the question post, update the code to not contain obvious problems (you have no `Opencvtest` target in your code, then there is no reason to use `${PROJECT_NAME}` in `target_link_libraries()`). Then re-run the code and paste the actual error message into the post.

Comment: I have edited the code through the questions, I have put Opencvtest into target_link_libraries(), still It does not work. Hope you can help me

Comment: I have edited the code through the questions, I have put Opencvtest into target_link_libraries(), still It does not work. Hope you can help me

Comment: New error message tells you that there is no `main.cpp` file near the `CMakeLists.txt` (in the same directory).

Comment: I found main.cpp through this path, but not sure is the right one
C:\Users\Astron\opencv\sources\samples\winrt_universal\VideoCaptureXAML\video_capture_xaml\video_capture_xaml.Shared

Comment: Should I copy it and paste in to directory that has CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: "Should I copy it and paste in to directory that has CMakeLists.txt?" - It is up to you. In `add_executable()` call you should specify path to the file. Relative paths (like in your current code) are interpreted relative to the current source dir (where `CMakeLists.txt` is located).

Comment: I don't understand  the add_executable() part can you explain it for me please?